# Default Data Protector - Owin Token Auth

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, owin, katana

I am attempting to implement a token auth solution using Owin and ASP.Net hosted on IIS and am having trouble getting the dafault data protection to work correctly on the bearer tokens that are being generated.  The solution seems to work fine except for the fact that I can generate bearer tokens from an auth server on one machine and the resource API can consume those tokens on another machine.  From everything I have researched, the validationKey in the machine.config file should be used to protect the token by default unless I implement my own data protection.  I've tried adding the machine key / validation key to my web.config as well with no luck.

The Configuration method in the Startup class looks like this:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        // Setup auth
        ConfigureOAuth(app);
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

How do I get the default data protection to work so that it's protecting the data using the validation key?  Is there another step in the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the **machineKey** node for both the Auth Server and Resource Server share the same machineKey in web.config files. You dont have to have any extra configuration setup.

OAuth middleware will use the default data protection provider in your Authorization Server, so it will use the "validationKey" value in **machineKey** node stored in machine.config file to issue the access token and protect it. The same case applies when you send the access token to your Resource Server, it will use the same **machineKey** to decrypt the access token and extract the authentication ticket from it.

*Courtesy - Taiseer Joudeh http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/24/decouple-owin-authorization-server-resource-server-oauth-2-0-web-api/.*